# Built in Middleware function

Tags: node.js, middleware

Built in middleware functions like `app.use(express.json())` and `app.get('/', () => res.send('Hello'))`.

I heard they can be called middleware functions too, I don't know if 'Built in Middleware function is the best term to call them. Do they terminate the cycle or do they automatically invoke the `next()` method, to pass control to the next middleware function?

Answer (score 0):

they automatically invoke the next() method .id execute successfully otherwise they will throw error

Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.
As name suggests it comes in middle of something and that is request and response cycle
Middleware has access to request and response object
Middleware has access to next function of request-response life cycle
Image for post
Middleware functions can perform the following tasks:
Execute any code.
Make changes to the request and the response objects.
End the request-response cycle.
Call the next middleware in the stack.
If the current middleware function does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.

Comment: Ah, but the trick is that while a link only answer isn't good, copying without attribution is worse. Please provide attribution for the quoted parts.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `app.get` or `app.use` are middleware functions. Middleware functions are those that you are passing as callbacks to the `app.get`, `app.use`, ...

In express, middleware functions have a predefined signature, either

```
function(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction)
```

or

```
function(err: Error, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction)
```

depending on whether it is normal or error middleware.

Any function that operates on an incoming request and have the above signature can be called a middleware function.

There are only two possible options that you can do in the middeware function, either you send a response to the requester or you call `next` function to pass the request to the next middleware (or forget to do any of there and wonder why the client seems stuck).

So yes, things like body-parsers, loggers, session handlers, ... do call `next` function otherwise your own request handlers wouldn't be executed at all (assuming they are preceded by the mentioned middleware functions).

Callbacks passed to `app.get` and similar methods are also middleware functions and you can call `next` within them and continue with another handler. Example

```js
// these are global middleware functions - they process every request
app.use(middleware1)
app.use(middleware2)
app.use(middleware3)

// functions middleware4 and middleware5 are executed only when GET / 
// request is received
app.get('/', middleware4, middleware5, (req, res) => {
    return res.send({})
})
```